Prevent RecyclerView from scrolling while zooming in ImageView using two fingers
I'm working on creating a photo gallery carousel where only one image is displayed at a time. I am using a RecyclerView to handle the horizontal scrolling between the images. However, I have encountered an issue when trying to implement zoom functionality on the images.
I am using a GestureDetector or similar touch handling to detect pinch-to-zoom gestures. The problem I am facing is that when I attempt to zoom in or out on an image using two fingers, the RecyclerView scroll action is triggered instead. This prevents me from properly zooming in or out on the images.
Here is a summary of my setup:

I have a RecyclerView to display one image at a time.
Each image can be zoomed in and out using a pinch gesture.

When I pinch to zoom, the RecyclerView sometimes captures the gesture and scrolls to the next or previous image, instead of zooming in on the current image.
I've tried overriding the touch events in the RecyclerView, but I couldn't prevent the scroll from being triggered while zooming. I also attempted to use a custom touch listener to differentiate between scroll and zoom gestures, but it hasn't worked as expected.
I would like to temporarily disable the RecyclerView scroll when a two-finger zoom gesture is detected, so that I can zoom in and out on the image without triggering the scroll action. How can I do this?

hint: preventing parent touch is done by invoking requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent on views parent during your touch event. You can try firing it as soon as second finger is pressed down.

Provide some of your code for a better response and to understand for all at which place you are facing the issue.

Try this inside onBindViewHolder where imageView stands for single image which is pinch-to-zoom.
holder.imageView.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
             view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
             return true;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
             return true;
     }
    return false;
});

